# SonarQube is reporting Remove this expression which always evaluates to “true”

Tags: java, sonarqube, sonarlint

I have the following code:

```java
final Set<String> desktopMediaCodes = getCodesByMediaDeviceType(mediaModels, MediaDeviceType.DESKTOP);
final Set<String> mobileMediaCodes = getCodesByMediaDeviceType(mediaModels, MediaDeviceType.MOBILE);
final Set<String> tabletMediaCodes = getCodesByMediaDeviceType(mediaModels, MediaDeviceType.TABLET);

//In case they are the same, only default.
if (desktopMediaCodes.equals(mobileMediaCodes) && mobileMediaCodes.equals(tabletMediaCodes)) {
    asset.setDefaults(desktopMediaCodes);
    return;
}

//In case three are different, we will send mobile, desktop and tablet.
if(!desktopMediaCodes.equals(mobileMediaCodes) && !desktopMediaCodes.equals(tabletMediaCodes) && !mobileMediaCodes.equals(tabletMediaCodes)){
    asset.setDesktop(desktopMediaCodes);
    asset.setMobile(mobileMediaCodes);
    asset.setTablet(tabletMediaCodes);
    return;
}

//In case only tablet is different, we will send default and tablet.
if(desktopMediaCodes.equals(mobileMediaCodes) && !mobileMediaCodes.equals(tabletMediaCodes)){
    asset.setDefaults(desktopMediaCodes);
    asset.setTablet(tabletMediaCodes);
    return;
}

//In case only desktop is different, we will send default and tablet.
if(mobileMediaCodes.equals(tabletMediaCodes) && !tabletMediaCodes.equals(desktopMediaCodes)){
    asset.setDefaults(mobileMediaCodes);
    asset.setDesktop(desktopMediaCodes);
    return;
}

//In case only mobile is different, we will send default and tablet.
if(tabletMediaCodes.equals(desktopMediaCodes) && !tabletMediaCodes.equals(mobileMediaCodes)){
    asset.setDefaults(tabletMediaCodes);
    asset.setMobile(mobileMediaCodes);
    return;
}
```

And SonarQube is reporting me that

[image: screen with issues]

(the yellow fields)

And that is not true, is this a bug or am I missing something ? SonarQube is confusing me.

Comment: It sure looks like a bug.

Comment: Why would tabletMediaCodes ever equal mobileMediaCodes? Unless the method returns the same object to each, those are going to be different sets, no?

Comment: It is not a bug. It is the outcome of combining all knowledge gained from the previous `if` expressions. Thats a good example of how powerful a linter can be.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to read the whole context. You have 5 if statements in your code. I'll simplify it a little bit:

```
1) D == M && M == T

2) D != M && D != T && M != T

3) D == M && M != T

4) M == T && D != T

5) D == T && D != M
```

Let's analyze the code.

### First issue

It informs you that `M != T` always evaluate to `true` in the 3rd line:

```
3) D == M && M != T
```

Why? Because your 1st line is:

```
1) D == M && M == T
```

It guaranties that only the following values are possible in 3rd line:

```
D == M && M != T
D != M && M != T
D != M && M == T
```

You can understand it as:

- if `D == M` then `M` must be != `T` (no sense to check `M != T`)
- if `D != M` then `M` may be = or != `T` (we have to check if `M` = or != `T`)

The new code is:

```
1) D == M && M == T

2) D != M && D != T && M != T

3) D == M

4) M == T && D != T

5) D == T && D != M
```

### Second issue

The same situation as in the first issue. `D != T` always evaluate to `true` in the 4th line:

```
4) M == T && D != T
```

because 3rd line:

```
3) D == M
```

guarantees that `D != M`. The 2nd line:

```
2) D != M && D != T && M != T
```

guarantees that:

```
D == T && M != T
D != T && M == T
D == T && M == T
```

We will remove the 3rd option because the 1st line catches it:

```
1) D == M && M == T
```

Now we have:

```
D == T && M != T
D != T && M == T
```

You can understand it as:

- if `D == M` then `M` must be != `T` (no sense to check `M != T`)
- if `D != M` then `M` must be = `T` (no sense to check `M == T`)

The new code is:

```
1) D == M && M == T

2) D != M && D != T && M != T

3) D == M

4) M == T

5) D == T && D != M
```

### Third and fourth issues

The whole if condition always evaluate to `true`. Let's read the 5th line:

```
5) D == T && D != M
```

The `M != D` is always true, because 3rd line guarantees it:

```
3) D == M
```

The new code is:

```
1) D == M && M == T

2) D != M && D != T && M != T

3) D == M

4) M == T

5) D == T
```

We can also remove `D == T` because:

```
3) D == M
4) M == T
```

At 5th line only the following option is possible: `D != M && M != T`. The 2nd line is:

```
2) D != M && D != T && M != T
```

If `D != T` then 2nd line catch it. It means the only possibility is `D == T`, so there is no sense to check it.

### The final code

```java
final Set<String> desktopMediaCodes = getCodesByMediaDeviceType(mediaModels, MediaDeviceType.DESKTOP);
final Set<String> mobileMediaCodes = getCodesByMediaDeviceType(mediaModels, MediaDeviceType.MOBILE);
final Set<String> tabletMediaCodes = getCodesByMediaDeviceType(mediaModels, MediaDeviceType.TABLET);

// In case they are the same, only default.
if (desktopMediaCodes.equals(mobileMediaCodes) && mobileMediaCodes.equals(tabletMediaCodes)) {
    asset.setDefaults(desktopMediaCodes);
    return;
}

// In case three are different, we will send mobile, desktop and tablet.
if (!desktopMediaCodes.equals(mobileMediaCodes) && !desktopMediaCodes.equals(tabletMediaCodes) && !mobileMediaCodes.equals(tabletMediaCodes)) {
    asset.setDesktop(desktopMediaCodes);
    asset.setMobile(mobileMediaCodes);
    asset.setTablet(tabletMediaCodes);
    return;
}

// In case only tablet is different, we will send default and tablet.
if (desktopMediaCodes.equals(mobileMediaCodes)) {
    asset.setDefaults(desktopMediaCodes);
    asset.setTablet(tabletMediaCodes);
    return;
}

// In case only desktop is different, we will send default and tablet.
if (mobileMediaCodes.equals(tabletMediaCodes)) {
    asset.setDefaults(mobileMediaCodes);
    asset.setDesktop(desktopMediaCodes);
    return;
}

// In case only mobile is different, we will send default and tablet.
asset.setDefaults(tabletMediaCodes);
asset.setMobile(mobileMediaCodes);
```

Comment: Excellent answer, very in-depth. Good approach by simplifying the expressions like that.